# Can we use between operator in sql server for deleteing range of rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have used between operator to delete some data from my Table "products".
But I have a doubt is it the right way to delete or not?
please tell me.....

```
here is the sample : delete from tbl_registration where regid between 1 and 20;
```

Comment: If your intention is to delete records having a `regid` value of 1, 2, ... 19, 20, then yes, your logic is correct.

Comment: Change the query to `select * from tbl_registration where regid between 1 and 20;` and check that the rows return is what you wanted to delete